# Does packages.config have to be in the project folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

Trying to tidy up my file structure, I moved packages.config to a subfolder. Only to discover it was not being picked up by Nuget any more.

Is it possible to move the file or is it hard-coded into VS that it must be in the same directory as the project file?

Googling doesn't give me an obvious answer, I just get general information on packages.config's purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does packages.config have to be in the project folder?

You cannot move that `packages.config` file into any other sub folder except the project's root folder.

Also, I agree with **thatguy**.

[Packages.config nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config) allows packages.config file be in the root directory of the project and nuget and msbuild will be able to recognize this file and manage the nuget packages in your project. **That's its mechanism.**

**So my suggestion is that you should move it back to the project's root directory.** And so far, this is the only way to ensure that you successfully manage packages using `packages.config`.

**Besides**, if you still want your request to come true, I suggest you could suggest a feature request on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(click **suggest a feature**). And The Team will consider your request carefully and I hope they will give you a satisfactory reply.

Comment: I think you have mis-typed the other user's name... hopefully accidentally as it's a bit of an awkward error?!

Answer (score 1):

> If used, packages.config is typically located in a project root. It's automatically created when the first NuGet operation is run, but can also be created manually before running any commands such as nuget restore.

This is from the `packages.config`  [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/reference/packages-config). Although it states that the configuration file is *typically located* in the project root, there is no indication on any requirements for moving it. Therefore, it might be a limitation of the Visual Studio Nuget package manager that expects the `packages.config` file in the project root. I have never seen any official documentation or a working example of moving this file without breaking the package manager.

Comment: You need one ``packages.config`` per project file because the version information in it must exactly match the MSBuild rules inside the project file. You can use ``NuGet.config`` to centralize the actual ``packages`` directory to avoid lots of copies of the target NuGets within a multi-project solution.